# Namespace handling and inheritance managing with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, namespaces

The following code should solve these issues:

1. Handle namespaces;
2. Be a class factory from Pojos
3. Be a object factory
4. Create a class with inheritance capabilities from a POJO  using [john resig inheritance implementation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/);
5. Handle singletons

Here is an example of it's usage:

```
var OliveOil=require('OliveOil')();
var handler=new OliveOil(MY_PATH_FOR_DEFAULT_CLASSES);
//This should load a class that is on MY_PATH_FOR_DEFAULT_CLASSES and create a object form it
var SimpleClass=handler.createObject('SimpleClass',param1,param2,param3);
handler.setNamespaceDir('business',PATH_TO_BUSINESS_MODULE);
//This should load a class on the path to business module with the name of controller
var businessController=handler.createObject('business.Controller',param1);
var childOfSimpleClassPojo={
  'parent':'SimpleClass',
   _param4:null,
   'init':function(param1,param2,param3,param4){
      this._super(param1,param2,param3);//Invoking parent constructor
      this._param4=param4; 
   }

}
handler.setClassFromPojo('ChildOfSimpleClass',childOfSimpleClassPojo);
//This should create a class based on the pojo, and also inherits from the previously laoded simpleClass
var simpleObject=handler.createObject('ChildOfSimpleClass',param1,param2,param3,param4);
```

Here is the full code for the application:

```
var Class = require('class.extend');
var util=require('util');
var fs=require('fs');
module.exports=function(){
     /**
 * This class handles the initialization of several components, as well as path mapping, inheritances and namespace colisions
 * It's serve as a common library for object,classes and paths lookup
 * @type {Object}
 */
var oliveOil={

    //A map of classes in which the namespace class name is the index and the class object the item
    classMap:{

    },
    //A map of classes to it's class path
    classFileMap:{

    },
    //A map of class names to objects, it is handled in our singletons objects
    objectMap:{

    },
    //A map of directories based on the namespace
    namespaceDirMap:{

    },
    noNamespaceDir:null,
    /**
     * Get a class object from the given object
     * @param  {[type]} namespace [description]
     * @return {[type]}           [description]
     */
    getClass:function(name){
        if(this.isClassSet(name)){
            return this.classMap[name];
        }
        if(this.loadClass(name)){
            return this.classMap[name];
        }
        else{
            throw new Error('Was not able to load the class '+name);
        }

    },
    loadClass:function(name){
        var classPojo=this.getClassFileContents(name);
        if(this.setClassFromPojo(name,classPojo)){
            return true;
        }
        throw new Error('Was not able to load the class '+name+' on the path '+this.classFileMap[name]);
    },
    isObjectSet:function(name){
        return !!this.objectMap[name];
    },
    isClassSet:function(name){
        return !!this.classMap[name];
    },
    createObject:function(name, var_args){
        //Getting the var_args
        var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        if(!this.isClassSet(name)){
            if(!this.loadClass(name)){
                throw new Error('The class "'+name+'" is not set');
            }
        }
        var DesiredClass=this.getClass(name);
        //Needed for us to apply the constructor
        var object = Object.create(DesiredClass.prototype);

        result= DesiredClass.apply(object, params);
        if (typeof result === 'object') {
            return result;
        }
        return object;



    },
    getClassFile:function(name){
        return this.classFileMap[name];
    },
    _getFile:function(path){
        if(path.indexOf('.js')!=path.length-3){
            path+='.js'
        }
        if(!fs.existsSync(path)){
            throw new Error('the path '+path+' does not exists');
        }
        return require(path);
    },
    getClassFileContents:function(name){
        if(!this.isClassFileSet(name)){
            var namespaceAndName=this.getNamespaceAndNameFromPath(name);
            var namespace=namespaceAndName['namespace'];
            var className=namespaceAndName['className'];
            if(namespace && !this.isNamespaceSet(namespace)){
                throw new Error('The namespace '+namespace+' is not set');
            }
            if(namespace){
                this.setClassFileByNamespace(namespace,className);
            }
            else{
                this.setClassFile(name,this.noNamespaceDir+name);
            }
        }


        return this._getFile(this.classFileMap[name]);

    },

    setClassFileByNamespace:function(namespace,className){
        var fullName=namespace+'.'+className;
        if(this.isClassFileSet(fullName)){
            throw new Error('The class '+className+' on the namespace '+namespace+' is already mapped');
        }
        var path=this.getNamespaceDir(namespace)+'/'+className;
        this.classFileMap[fullName]=path;
        return true;
    },
    getNamespaceAndNameFromPath:function(name){
        var pos=name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if(pos==-1){
            return {
                'namespace':false,
                'className':name
            }
        }
        return {
            'namespace':name.substr(0,pos),
            'className':name.substr(pos+1)
        };
    },
    getNamespaceFromPath:function(name){
        var pos=name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if(pos==-1){
            throw new Error(name+' is not a valid namespace');
        }
        return name.substr(0,pos);

    },
    getClassNameFromPath:function(name){
        var pos=name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if(pos==-1){
            throw new Error(name+ '  is not a namespace');
        }
        return name.substr(pos+1);

    },
    getSingletonObject:function(name,var_args){
        if(this.isObjectSet(name)){
            return this.objectMap[name];
        }
        this.objectMap[name]=this.createObject.apply(this,arguments);
        return this.objectMap[name];
    },
    /**
     * Sets a class on the given namespace to be the class object
     * @type {[type]}
     */
    setClassFromPojo:function(name,pojoData){
        var ParentClass;
        if(pojoData.parent){
            ParentClass=this.getClass(pojoData.parent);
        }
        else{
            ParentClass=Class;
        }
        return this.setClass(name,ParentClass.extend(pojoData));

    },

    /**
     * Sets a class on the given namespace to be the class object
     * @type {[type]}
     */
    setClass:function(name,classObject){
        if(this.isClassSet(name)){
            throw new Error('The class '+name+' is already set');
        }
        this.classMap[name]=classObject;
        return true;
    },
    setMultipleNamespacesDir:function(namespaceMap){
        for(var name in namespaceDirMap){
            this.setNamespaceDir(name,namespaceDirMap[name]);
        }
        return true;
    },
    setNamespaceDir:function(name,dir){
        if(this.isNamespaceSet(name)){
            throw new Error('The namespace '+name+' is already set');
        }
        this.namespaceDirMap[name]=dir;
        return true;
    },
    getNamespaceDir:function(name){

        return this.namespaceDirMap[name];
    },
    isNamespaceSet:function(name){
        return !!this.namespaceDirMap[name];
    },
    isClassFileSet:function(name){
        return !!this.classFileMap[name];

    },
    setClassFile:function(name,file){
        if(this.isClassFileSet(name)){
            throw new Error('The class '+name+' is already set with a path');
        }
        this.classFileMap[name]=file;
        return true;
    },
    setObject:function(name,object){
        if(this.isObjectSet(name)){
            throw new Error('The object '+name+' is already set');
        }
        this.objectMap[name]=object;
    },
    init:function(noNamespaceDir){
        this.noNamespaceDir=noNamespaceDir;
    }
};
    return  Class.extend(oliveOil);
}
```

What improvements could I make?